# kubectl create deployment not has the option containerPort

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I execute `kubectl create deployment nginx --image nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml` it does not have options `--port` or `--containerPort`.  My yaml is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Is there a way to generate yaml with the `containerPort` option?

Answer (score 2):

From [the kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#-strong-api-overview-strong-) I see this example:

```
$ echo 'apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-example
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.11
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
' | kubectl replace -f -
```

So under your `containers` entry you should be able to add:

```
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Is that what you had in mind or, at least, good enough?  You seem to want this as a command line option for the `kubectl` command and I don't see anything that indicates this is possible.